# Submenu click event is not getting fired up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below markup which displays submenus

```
<ul class="list-unstyled collapse show" id="pageSubmenu" style="">
  <li><a href="">Report 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Report 2</a></li>
  <li><a href=""> Report 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery to handle click event is as below

```
 $("#pageSubmenu li a").click(function () {
      $(this).children('a').trigger('click');
      alert('clicked');
  });
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: `$(this).children('a').trigger('click');` <- what exactly are you trying to accomplish here? You're targeting the `a` elements within the `a` elements that were clicked to begin with. There are none.

Comment: @Jeto I want to get the values like "Report 1", "Report 2" when those submenus are clicked

Comment: @RAM instead of `trigger`, use `location.href`  Refer;  https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/4425004

Comment: You can get those values by `$(this).text()` - then insert them into your document, or log them, or whatever. PS it's best not to use `<a>` tags unless you actually want a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#pageSubmenu li a").click(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled collapse show" id="pageSubmenu" style="">
  <li><a href="#">Report 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Report 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Report 3</a></li>
</ul>
```